# want to develop a nodejs and java script frame like express

Tags: express

I want to develop a framework like express. I am very keen to know the insides of Express-JS. Can some one suggest me how to develop a framework in Javascript and nodejs ? I cant find sources to learn how to develop framework in node ? please help me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will not find sources  because it is something hard to do,

> Writing a framework is a big project that requires a broad understanding of what the framework will do, how it plans to accomplish it and most importantly embody the ideals that you have about developing front end architecture

If you're new, the breadth of your knowledge will be limited by your experiences.

How about focusing on making  nifty tools or JavaScript-based programs